# LinqToSql and the DataContext 101

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'm looking for a good article or two, or just an explanation, on how the DataContext, or dbml file, for LinqToSql, exactly works in LinqToSql.

- Is this a disconnected environment?
- Are the database connections still pooled by Sql Server?
- If I create an instance of my DataContext am I responsible to Dispose of it?
- How does it handle a multiple user environment, when my application creates a new DataContext object, does each thread get it's own DataContext?

And a bunch of other questions as well as what are some best practices!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DataContext FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx) at MSDN

[Rick Strahl Article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx) on DataContext Lifetime

Base site for [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) on MSDN.

The [LINQ Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) at MSDN.

The [LINQ Project Forum](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/showforum.aspx?siteid=1&forumid=123)

[DataContext class description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx)